# Pointwise, Uniform convergence on [a, ∞)

Tags: calculus, limits, uniform-convergence

$f_n(x) = \frac{n^2x}{1+n^3x^2}$

I claim the above function is continuous.

For $[a, ∞) , a>0$

I have tried and found out that it is pointwise convergent.

For uniform convergence,
I found out that $| f_n(x) - f(x)| < \frac{1}{n^4a^3} < \epsilon$
so it is uniform convergent, but I heard that uniform convergence is only on a close interval?

Comment: Uniform convergence is simply the condition that $N(\epsilon)$ is independent of $x$. From the inequality above, you can claim the for $N(\epsilon) = (\frac{1}{a^3 \epsilon})^{1/4} $ is good enough for every $x$, so yes, uniform continuity follows. By this result, you don't need a closed interval to have uniform convergence of a sequence of functions :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Uniform convergence is not only (and not always) on closed intervals.
2. The interval $[a,+\infty)$ is actually closed.